# Mercurial: get report with current repository state

Tags: mercurial

I use a Mercurial integration repository with several sub-repositories. Is there any command to get some kind of report or overview of the current repository state?

I would like to get the actual hash code of every repository and changed files within the sub repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The status command is aware of sub-repositories and will list every file in the main and all of its sub-repos:

```
hg status --subrepos
```

In its output it assumes that every subrepo has checked-out the revision as recoreded in the .hgsubstate file in the main repo; otherwise it shows the diff wrt that version for the respective subrepo.

I know no nice solution to check for the proper version being checked out. However you can obtain that with a bit of bash foo:

```
for i in $(cat .hgsubstate | cut -f2 -d\  ); do
  if [ "$(hg log -r. -R$i --template='{node}')" != "$(cat .hgsubstate | grep $i$ | cut -f1 -d\  )" ]; then
    echo "$i has different checked-out version"
  fi
done
```